# using keyEvent from different classes

Tags: java

im trying to put restrictions on movement if my chicken reaches the corner here is my code for my move method

```
public void move1(){


    if(((x<=350) && (y>=350)) || ((x>=450) && (y>=350))){
        if(dy<0){
            dy=0;
        }
    }
    if(((x>=350) && (y<=350)) || ((x<=450) && (y<=350))){
        if(dx<0 || dx>0){
            dx=0;
        }
    }

    if(((y<=250) && (x<=350)) || ((y<=250) && (x>=450))){
        if(dy>0){
        dy=0;
        }
    }
    if (x >= 750){ 
    x = 750; 
    } 
    if (y >= 575){
    y = 575; 
    }
    x += dx;y += dy; 

}
```

i used a key adapter for the movement of my chicken but its from a different class

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
            chick.keyPressed(e); 
                    }
```

the animation is perfectly fine but my chicken wont respond the keyevent

Comment: can you share the chick.keyPressed(e); method?

Comment: It's probably more likely a focus issue with our component, `KeyListeners` are well known for this problem.  A better choice would be to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  It would also be better that you tell the model what you want to do in response to an event, rather then giving the event to the object (this way you can change what the events do ;))

Comment: `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            fire();
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 1;
        }
    }`

Comment: im new in java so i dont think i would be able to do it with key binding. i have read the documentation but i dont seem to understand how it works. is there any other way for my chicken to move?

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer : +1, for your chicken though, hope it moves :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to have a look at [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), they are more accustomed to such situations, which are more concerned about focus related issues. This post regarding [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), might will surely interest you, on the topic concern :-)

## EDIT :

Here a small program from help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBindingExample
{
    private DrawingBoard contentPane;
    /*
     * There variables will simply
     * decide how much the square
     * will move with click key press,
     * in this case I have set this to
     * 1 (inside the constructor).
     * brakes will simply tell whether
     * the square will move or not in
     * a given direction.
     */
    private int speed;
    private int brakes;

    public KeyBindingExample() {
        speed = 5;
        brakes = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new DrawingBoard(10, 10, Color.BLUE.darker());

        addBindingsToBoard();

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addBindingsToBoard() {
        /*
         * Since, when UP Arrow is pressed, that means, the square
         * can move vertically upwards, hence, the square will move
         * along Y-Axis that too in the negative direction of the 
         * same, though along X-Axis the square will move nowhere,
         * hence, we passing 0 and -1, since we want to add the 
         * current location (say square is at present at 50, 50),
         * now after UP Arrow key event, square will be at (50, 49);
         */
        putBindingsFor(contentPane, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),
                                "UP Arrow Key", brakes, -speed);
        /*
         * When RIGHT Arrow is pressed, the square is suppose to
         * move horizontally, along the X-Axis, in the positive
         * direction towards the RIGHT. Hence +1 change along X-Axis
         * and no change along Y-Axis, i.e. from (50, 49), the square
         * will now move to (51, 49), that's why we passing (+1, 0)
         */
        putBindingsFor(contentPane, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),
                                "RIGHT Arrow Key", speed, brakes);
        /*
         * When DOWN Arrow is pressed, the square is suppose to
         * move vertically, along the Y-Axis, in the positive
         * direction towards the BOTTOM. Hence no change along X-Axis
         * and +1 change along Y-Axis, i.e. from (51, 49), the square
         * will now move to (51, 50), that's why we passing (0, +1)
         */
        putBindingsFor(contentPane, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"),
                                "DOWN Arrow Key", brakes, +speed);
        /*
         * When LEFT Arrow is pressed, the square is suppose to
         * move horizontally, along the X-Axis, in the negative
         * direction towards the LEFT side. Hence -1 change along X-Axis
         * and no change along Y-Axis, i.e. from (51, 50), the square
         * will now move to (50, 50), that's why we passing (-1, 0).
         * The square will atlast come to it's initial position.
         */
        putBindingsFor(contentPane, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),
                                "LEFT Arrow Key", -speed, brakes);
    }

    private void putBindingsFor(JComponent comp,
        KeyStroke keyStroke, String value, final int moveX, final int moveY) {
        comp.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, value);
        comp.getActionMap().put(value, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                contentPane.setValues(moveX, moveY);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new KeyBindingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class DrawingBoard extends JPanel {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color rectColor;

    public DrawingBoard(int x, int y, Color rColor) {
        setOpaque(true);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        rectColor = rColor;
        width = height = 10;
    }

    public void setValues(int deltaX, int deltaY) {

        System.out.format("Firstly X : %d\tY : %d%n", x, y);
        repaint(x, y, width, height);
        /*
         * Whatever values are passed from above, i.e.
         * say on Left ARROW, we passing (-1, 0),
         * therefore deltaX will be -1 and deltaY will
         * be 0. Now whatever the current value of X is
         * we are simply adding deltaX to that value
         * and the same goes for deltaY as well.
         * Now since the value for x and y is updated
         * after these two statements below, we checking
         * that whether these two updated values lies
         * within the bounds of our board or not.
         * If they are, then we simply calling repaint,
         * to draw the square at this new location, else
         * we simply bring back the previous values of 
         * x and y to their previous state.
         */
        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;

        if ((x + width) <= getWidth() && (y + height) <= getHeight()
                        && x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
            System.out.format("Later X : %d\tY : %d%n", x, y);
            repaint(x, y, width, height);
        }
        else {
            x -= deltaX;
            y -= deltaY;
            System.out.format("Later X : %d\tY : %d%n", x, y);
            repaint(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Make this a customary habbit of overridding
     * this method whenever you have to override
     * any JComponent, instead of calling
     * setPreferredSize(...).
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(100, 100));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(rectColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer : If you want, I will add comments in the program, if that might make it even more easier for you to understand the logic and how the flow is moving ... !!! Please do let me know, if that is the need :-)

Comment: i would be delighted!

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer : Please do see the edits. I hope it helps :-) Else you can always ask your queries anytime, I be happy to answer :-)

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer : If you are trying to make a game, then I would be wise, that you call only that region on the board, which needs to be painted anew, instead of painting the whole board again and again, even though a minute change has taken place. Please do see this updated code, with more effective call to `repaint(withArguments)` instead of the previous `repaint(noArguments)`. Hope that be of more help :-)