# java keyevent not work as desired

Tags: java, swing

i'm going to create simple typing game in java.so i created new class wordpanel which extends jpanel .everything works fine expect key-event .when i press a key foreground of all first jlable of panels should be changed to yellow.but i recognize that line not execute because even when i put `sout()` i didn't get output.i can't find what is the wrong of this code.this my code

```
public class wordPanel extends JPanel{

    public wordPanel(String word) {

        setOpaque(true);
        char letters[];
        letters = word.toCharArray();
        JLabel lab[]=new JLabel[letters.length];
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, letters.length));
        for(int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
            lab[i]=new JLabel(letters[i]+"");
            this.add(lab[i]);
        }

        this.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
               char ch = evt.getKeyChar();
                   lab[0].setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                   System.out.println("hey");
            }
        });



    }

}
```

this is object creating block

```
        wordPanel wp1=new wordPanel("hello");
        Dimension d = wp1.getPreferredSize();

        wp1.setBounds(rand.nextInt((500 - 5) + 1) + 5, rand.nextInt((300 - 5) + 1) + 5, d.width, d.height);
        jPanel1.add(wp1);
        revalidate();
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PiumiWandana: You might have to use __[setFocusable(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable-boolean-)__ along with __[requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow--)__, though as stated in the answer, __[KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)__ is a way to go with Swing. KeyListeners are way too low level, which is to be used with `AWT`.

Comment: @PiumiWandana: I hope this small [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18314884/1057230), will be of some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing is not meant to use KeyListeners, using a Key Binding will work way better, and you don't have to worry about focus as much.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Keybinding is hard, here is a tutorial:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that other components on top of the panel receive the key event.
Try adding this keylistener to other components.